# use of a deleted function std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, move, copy-constructor

The error seems to be in the functions insert and printTree. I know that this error is caused by unique_ptr being not copy-able. But I thought that providing move and copy semantics should help me solve it. 
   My Questions

1. Have I made the copy and move constructors correct ?
2. If NO. How should I redesign the code. Please list out fundamental mistakes and how to correct them.
3. How can I incorporate Node* parent in the class?
4. Few tips on good code practices in such cases would be helpful

   ```
   // This is implementation of binary search tree.

       #ifndef BinarySearchTree_H

       #define BinarySearchTree_H


       #include <cstdio>
       #include <functional>
       #include <utility>
       #include <vector>
       #include <iostream>
       #include <memory>

       //template declaration
       template <class ValueType>

       class BinarySearchTree
       {

           struct Node
           {
               ValueType value;

               std::unique_ptr<Node> left;
               std::unique_ptr<Node> right;

               //Node *parent=nullptr; // How can I use parent in the class ?

               Node(){}

               //Node(const ValueType& value,std::unique_ptr<Node> left,std::unique_ptr<Node> right):value(value),left(left),right(right){}

               Node (const ValueType& value):value(value),left(nullptr),right(nullptr){}

           };

           std::unique_ptr<Node> root;

           void insert(const ValueType& value, std::unique_ptr<Node> node)
           {
               if(value< node->value)
               {
                   if(node->left)
                   {
                       insert(value,node->left);
                   }

                   else
                   {
                       std::unique_ptr<Node> left=std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(value));
                       node->left=left;
                   }

               }

               else
               {
                   if(node->right)
                   {
                       insert(value,node->right);
                   }

                   else
                   {
                       std::unique_ptr<Node> right=std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(value));
                       node->right=right;
                       //right->parent=node;
                   }
               }
           }

           void printNode(std::unique_ptr<Node> node)
           {
               if(!node)
               {
                   std::cout<<"No element in the tree\n";
               }
               else
               {
                   if(node->left)
                   {
                       std::cout<<node->left->value<<" ";
                   }
                   std::cout<<node->value<<" ";
                   if(node->right)
                   {
                       std::cout<<node->right->value<<" ";
                   }
               }
           }

       public:

           BinarySearchTree():root(nullptr){}
           ~BinarySearchTree(){}

           BinarySearchTree( BinarySearchTree && rhs):root(std::move(rhs.root)){}

           BinarySearchTree& operator=(BinarySearchTree && rhs )
           {
               root=std::move(rhs.root);
               return *this;
           }

           BinarySearchTree& operator=(const BinarySearchTree & rhs )
           {
               if(this!=&rhs)
               root.reset(rhs.root);
               return *this;
           }

           void insert(const ValueType& value)
           {
               if(root==nullptr)
               {
                   root=std::unique_ptr<Node>(new Node(value));

               }

               else
               {
                   insert(value,root);
               }
           }
          // void remove(const ValueTypr& value);

          void printTree(const BinarySearchTree& tree)
          {
               if(tree.root)
               {
                   if(tree.root->left)
                   {
                       printNode(tree.root->left);
                   }
                   printNode(tree.root);
                   if(tree.root->right)
                   {
                       printNode(tree.root->right);
                   }
               }

               else
               {
                   std::cout<<"tree is empty\n";
                   return;
               }
          }

       };



       #endif // BinarySearchTree
   ```

Comment: You really should not think about the new smart pointers as pointers in the old "normal" way, instead you should think of them more as resource ownership: Can a resource only have a single owner at a time (`std::unique_ptr`) or have many simultaneous owners (`std::shared_ptr`)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg. I know that unique_ptrs have only single ownership. My problem comes with my inability to construct move and copy semantics for the BinaryTree.

Comment: Sorry for perhaps sounding impolite, but what part of "single ownership" makes thinks you *could* implement any kind of copying? You can't copy the `std::unique_ptr` object, you can't copy the pointer inside it (then you have two `std::unique_ptr` object containing the same pointer, while will lead to bad things), the only way is to actually create brand new nodes and copy only the value. You might need to rethink your design, or at least the implementation of the design you have.

Answer (score 4):

1. No. You cannot copy unique pointers. You have to decide whether deep copies of your tree are meaningful or not.
2. Use move constructor and move assignment operator instead of copy constructor and copy assignment operator.
3. Add a raw pointer `Node* parent`. A parent owns its children, not vice-versa.
4. Use `std::make_unique()`. Avoid including headers you don't need. Is there a reason why `printTree()` doesn't work on `this`? Generally, you could use slightly a more readable syntax (indentation, empty lines etc.)

Comment: the error in printTree function that the compiler is giving  points to initialization of the printNode function. Error pointing to this " initializing argument 1 of 'void BinarySearchTree<ValueType>::printNode(std::unique_ptr<BinarySearchTree<ValueType>::Node>) [with ValueType = int]'|